# Symbol for iterated composition

Tags: notation

For numbers $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ one may write
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^n x_i
$$
for what might otherwise informally be written $x_1 + \cdots + x_n$.

For functions $f_1, \ldots, f_n$ is there similar notation for what might otherwise informally be written as $f_1 \circ \cdots \circ f_n$?

Comment: I've never seen any, but you do sometimes see composition written as concatenation (e.g. working with linear transformations), in which case a good old-fashioned $\prod$ could arguably work. You'd have to make sure there was no call for pointwise multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

> **Hint:** The paper *[Notation for Iteration of Functions, Iteral](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.0152.pdf)* by Valerii Salov from 2012 gives a survey of used notation of iterated functions. He also proposes a new notation, a so-called *Iteral-operator* to describe iteration of functions.